# Remove Response Header - nuSOAP Server Side Instance

Tags: php, ws-security, nusoap, pci-dss

I  need to be able to restrict what is being sent via send_response() method of nuSOAP at the server end.

When $server->service ( $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA ) it automatically  calls private method send_response()

https://sourcecodebrowser.com/nusoap/0.7.3/class_8soap__server_8php_source.html ( See line 236 - 282

I need to suppress this header at the server level.. Any help would be very much appreciated. Here's my piece of code

```
$server = new soap_server ();
$server->configureWSDL ( "wsprocessor", "urn:wsprocessor" );
$server->register ( "getRequestReturnResponse", array (
        "$inputXml" => "xsd:string"
), array (
        "return" => "xsd:string"
), "urn:wsprocessor", "urn:wsprocessor#getRequestReturnResponse", "rpc", "encoded", "Get Response back from server as XML String" );

$server->service ( $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA );
```

Answer (score 1):

Okay.. The answer to this query is a small hack.. After

```
$server->service ( $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA );
//Call the following 
header_remove('X-SOAP-Server');
header_remove('X-SOAP-Server:');
header_remove('X-Powered-By');
header_remove('X-Powered-By:');
```

Whatever header that needs to be removed.. say so

Comment: Where I need to add these lines? Can any one explain clearly?